# passing all the contents of a file as keywords after grep command

Tags: grep

Suppose I have two files named `a.txt` and `b.txt`. Is there any way to use all the contents of file `a.txt` to use as  patterns for grep command if I want to search in file `b.txt`?

General format of `grep` is:

```
grep 'pattern' 'filename'
```

Comment: Downvoted: homework detected.

Answer (score 0):

A full solution:

```
grep -f a.txt b.txt
```

Alternative style, applicable to a list of *literal* patterns (not regexps):

```
fgrep "`cat a.txt`" b.txt
```

Note that the `fgrep` command is equivalent to `grep -F`. The latter is a cheap, non-foolproof solution assuming the `a.txt` doesn’t start from the hyphen-minus character `-`.

Comment: How I will use this as a pipeline with my command I sated in the post? @Incnis Mrsi

Comment: @Black: Don’t understand where is “**your** command” specified. Is English your native tongue?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cat a.txt | grep -f - b.txt
```

or ( if you like `<( )` )

```
grep -f <(cat a.txt) b.txt
```

Comment: Challenging to become UL champion for the [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)?

Comment: just playing "edoc flog" ...